# finding index.html on sidebar in visual studio code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, sidebar

Hi so I was trying to learn json for the first time and in the tutorial theres a section where you need to open index.html but that is not on my sidebar and I have absolutely no clue how to find/open it.

In the tutorial theres a drop down marked as "current project" which is not present on my screen and the index.html is in that. Is there an easy way to find where this is?
for anyone curious the tutorial im following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiADhChRriM and I saw at 6:43 it was there when he opened the program

[this is my sidebar for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Xwo.jpg)

idk if im just dumb or my progam is being stupid but i need to find the answer so i can continue this project as soon as possible

Comment: before I get a question on it, the "physicsdemoassessment" was another project from months ago i did in unity for college. Idk why its there because we didn't use Visual Studio Code in that project

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is how the visual studio code side bar works, the first line you see (`open editors`) is a list of all open files, you don't have to pay mind to it,
but you can use it to find files you were editing earlier if you want.

The second line (`physicsdemoassessment`) is your current directory, there you can see all files on the directory.

This means that visual studio code is currently open on your old project, you say you didn't use it, but you probably opened vs code at some point on your project once, and vs code remembers.

You should make a new project to follow the tutorial. Go to File->Open Folder and pick a folder or make an empty folder and select it.

The reason why the tutorial's side bar says `current project` is because that is the name of the folder he's working on. so if you want to name your project that as well you should name the folder you open that.

Finally, to "find" the `index.html` file, as he explains in the video, this is just a very basic file, he made it before the tutorial started, it's not a vs code thing. You have to write the file yourself.

I hope my explanation was clear and solves your issue.